# Matlab:Reading textfile into matrix

Tags: matlab, textscan

I want to read data from a text file in Matlab. The file describes a surface consists of two parts:
1)A header with information on x,y dimensions in pixels and nm etc.
2)Matrix with height values (512x512)

When I try to read just the matrix first I end up with a single column vector instead of a matrix
`C = textscan(id,'%f','HeaderLines',18,'Delimiter','\t')`
The file contains " " seperated values and the lines seperated the rows of the matrix. It works when I manually delete the header and read it with
`A=dlmread(path,'\t',[0 0 511 511]);`

I want to obtain the same 512x512 matrix with textscan so that I can later also parse the header - how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not strictly bound to `textscan`, you may use `fscanf` instead (see [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)). Like this:

```
fid = fopen('FileName.txt');

% here you have to skip (or parse) your header lines
% and determine number of rows/columns in your data matrix

A = fscanf(fid, '%g', [NColumns NRows]);
fclose(fid);

% Transpose so that A matches
% the orientation of the file
A = A';
```

**UPDATE1**

This code might be not very elegant, but it will parse your header into **FileInfo** structure so you may use the data later in your code.

```
% sample file header
%
% # File Format = ASCII
% # Created by SPIP 6.2.8.0 2014-08-15 20:41
% # Original file: D:\...
% # x-pixels = 512
% # y-pixels = 512
% # x-length = 319375
% # y-length = 319375
% # x-offset = 0
% # y-offset = 0
% # z-unit = [nm]
% # scanspeed = 638.75
% # forcecurve = 0
% # voidpixels =76
% # description =62:Confocal Height Image  Date: 2013-08-20T13:36 User: Unknown
% # Start of Data: MATRIX

fid = fopen('text.txt','r');

FileInfo  = [];
tmpString = '';   % initializing the s
while isempty(strfind(tmpString,'Start of Data: MATRIX'))

    % we read a string from file
    tmpString = fgetl(fid);
    % and split it into left and right parts according to the '=' position
    [kev,val] = strtok( tmpString(3:end) , ':=' );

    % remove spaces from key name and make it a valid variable name in MatLab
    keyName = genvarname( strrep(strrep(kev,'-',''),' ','') );

    % check if key value is a number
    [x,OK]    = str2num(strtrim(val(2:end)));

    % if value is a number, use it otherwise leave the trimmed original string
    if OK
        FileInfo.(keyName) = x;
    else
        FileInfo.(keyName) = strtrim(val(2:end));
    end

end

% Now we can read the data
A = fscanf(fid, '%g', [FileInfo.xpixels FileInfo.ypixels]);
fclose(fid);

% Transpose so that A matches
% the orientation of the file
%A = A';
```

Comment: Thanks - it works. But I have problems with parsing the head. Is there a way to parse the first n-lines of a document? Or parse it until the String "Data:"? I read the documentation on formatSpec but I dont get it right for some reason.

Comment: Everything depends on the way the header is formed, there is no general rule. Can you provide an example?

Comment: `# File Format = ASCII
# Created by SPIP 6.2.8.0 2014-08-15 20:41
# Original file: D:\...
# x-pixels = 512
# y-pixels = 512
# x-length = 319375
# y-length = 319375
# x-offset = 0
# y-offset = 0
# z-unit = [nm]
# scanspeed = 638.75
# forcecurve = 0
# voidpixels =76
# description =62:Confocal Height Image

Date: 2013-08-20T13:36
User: Unknown
# Start of Data:
MATRIX` I just need the x&y sizes and get to Matrix after that. (Each # is in a new line, stackoverflow just changed it)

Comment: Thanks a lot. fgetl is the solution I was looking for, thanks also for the help with the implementation of the parsing!